# They all relate to one thing

Tags: knowledge

> 1:  $60$ $60$ $60$ 
>    2: $\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$ 
>    3: $\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$ 
>    4: $\frac{21}{7}$ 
>    5: 25, 36, ? 
>    6: $>90$

Find what all of these mean or what they represent

(What I mean is that tell me what each of 1 to 6 is)

Hint 1:

> When I read the answer given, I can’t help but laugh

Hint 2:

> @Glorfindel got the topic right

Hint 3:

> For #5, it has nothing to do with square numbers or equations relating to it

Hint 4:

> Five relates to one in a way

Hint 5:

> As in angles. I just picked random two numbers so that both of them added up wouldn't be greater than 179 degrees

Hint 6:

> You need to find the other angle

Answer (score 5):

I can link at least four to a common theme:

> triangles

as follows:

> 1. the angles of an [equilateral triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equilateral_triangle)
>  2. the formula for the [pyramid numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramidal_number); four sides of those pyramids look like triangles
>  3. [Heron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula) for the area of a triangle
>  4. a simple division yielding 3, the number of sides in a triangle
>  5. 49 — given 25, 36 or 49 equilateral triangles, it's possible to create another one with sides 5, 6 resp. 7 times the original (like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/203873/228959))
>  6. an [obtuse triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acute_and_obtuse_triangles) has an angle greater than 90 degrees

Comment: 4 might simply be rot13(guerr fvqrf)!!

Comment: @Stiv could be, but why this specific numerator & denominator?

Comment: 5 can be rot13(Clguntberna gurberz) or rot13(nphgr gevnatyr)

Comment: About 4: Gur cv nccebkvzngvba, nygubhtu vg'f npghnyyl 22/7

Comment: @Glorfindel You got 5 wrong... I'll add a hint

Comment: rot13(Onfrq ba gur bc'f uvagf, gur nafjre gb #5 frrzf gb or "119", gur qrterrf bs gur zvffvat natyr (fnzr flagnk nf #1))

Answer (score 0):

> 1) 60,60,60 The sum of the three angles of any triangle in Euclidian space is 180 degrees.
>  2) the number of squares in a $n*n$ square grid
>  3) Heron's formula for area of triangles
>  4) trisection
>  5) 5-2=3,  6-3=3. This is the only relation I can see between 1 and 5.
>  6) triangle with an angle greater than 90 degrees

Comment: For number 5 we can answer also as follows, (3^2+6^2)-(2^2+5^2)=4^2  so we have 16,25,36.